# Solutions for virtually splitting a text file

Tags: java, file-io, inputstream, filereader

I need to read & process a huge text file. To improve the data processing time, I thought of reading it concurrently by having multiple readers. The idea is to virtually split the file by noting down the start and end pointers. This is done by the main thread at the start of the program. By virtually I mean, not creating physical split files.

Later when reading and processing is to be done by concurrent readers, each thread could call bufferedReader.skip(long) and keep track of the number of characters read so that they do not cross the end pointer boundry.

The issue is file reading done by individual threads is done using BufferedReader  and hence to skip I need to know the number of characters while the main thread cannot determine this.  To calculate the start and end pointers the only data main thread has is the file length which is in bytes.

How do I determine the start and end pointers in terms of characters so that the reader can skip those many characters?

Note –

1. The input text file could be in different character encodings e.g. ASCII, EBCDIC, UTF-8, UTF-16 etc.
2. Reading the input file line by line to determine the start and end pointers is not an option as it defeats the purpose of splitting the text file.

**Update**

Note I am restricted to use java file API instead of frameworks like Hadoop. This is an application architecture restriction

**Update**

Here is code for reading the input file by skipping a calculated number of bytes and then reading the input file byte by byte to determine the record delimiter. Reply with your thoughts if you see issues with the code (especially considering the fact that the input file could be in different character encodings).

```
        {
        CountingInputStream countingInputStream = new CountingInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputFilePath.toFile()));
        long endPointer;
        while(true) {
            long actualSkipped = countingInputStream.skip(skipCount);
            if(actualSkipped == 0) {
                logger.info("Nothing to skip");
                break; //nothing to skip now.
            }

            byte[] inputBytes = new byte[recordDelimiterBytes.length];
            int noOfBytesRead = countingInputStream.read(inputBytes);
            if(noOfBytesRead == -1) {
                //end of file already reached!
                endPointer = countingInputStream.getCount();                    
                break;
            }
            while (!(Arrays.equals(recordDelimiterBytes, inputBytes))) {
                shiftLeft(inputBytes);
                int readByte = countingInputStream.read();

                if(readByte != -1) {
                    inputBytes[inputBytes.length - 1] = (byte) readByte;
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("EOF reached before getting the delimiter");
                }

            }
            endPointer = countingInputStream.getCount();
    }

    private void shiftLeft(byte[] inputBytes) {
        for(int i=0; i<inputBytes.length - 1; i++) {
            inputBytes[i] = inputBytes[i+1];
        }
    }
```

Comment: How big is _huge_? What's in the text file?

Comment: also, what is involved with processing the file?

Comment: MapReduce sounds like what you'll likely need, due to the inability to have multiple readers reading the same file concurrently. You may wish to look into Hadoop: http://hadoop.apache.org/

Comment: For reasons like the physical file system, substitute BufferedReader by java nio's memory mapped byte buffer. Go for asynchrone reading / processing.

Comment: @jlordo - Huge is in GB's - Above 10 Gb and can go upto 100 gb

Comment: @ninesided - Processing the file involves validating, filtering, converting and transforming data.

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl - Please have a look at my update in the description for the Hadoop suggestion

Comment: @JoopEggen - Asynchronous file reading will not help here since the record as a whole matters and not individual bytes. The application will have to wait till all bytes that make up a record are read. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AndyDufresne I meant processing a memory mapped file. The second best would be a random access file. BufferedReader won't fit in any way.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of points in your Question that need an answer:

> To improve the data processing time, I thought of reading it concurrently by having multiple readers.

If your processing is I/O bound, then trying to read a single file with multiple streams is unlikely to give you any speed up.  And it might make things worse.  However, it is difficult to give a definitive answer, because it depends on things like how the OS deals with read ahead, in-memory file system buffering, RAID and other factors.

On the other hand, if the processing is CPU bound, is amenable to parallelization, and you have multiple cores available, then multiple streams could be effective.

> How do I determine the start and end pointers in terms of characters so that the reader can skip those many characters?

You work out what the approximate partition sizes, and approximate boundaries.  Then you need to do a bit of work to find the exact boundaries.

- If you want to start each segment at the start of a line, or word.  Pick a point, and read one byte at a time until you reach the relevant boundary.
- If you want to start at the start of the next valid character:

  - The problem is trivial for an 8-bit encoding such as ASCII, Latin-1 etc.
  - With UTF-8 you skip to the next byte whose top bits are 00, 01 or 11, and that is the start of a code-point.  Refer to the table on the [Wikipedia page on UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description).
  - With UTF-16 you have to read byte pairs.  If you don't know the order (big-endian or little-endian) you can check the first 2 bytes to see if they are a BOM.  Having established that, a byte pair that is NOT in the range DC00-DFFF is the start of a code point.  Refer to the [Wikipedia page on UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

Obviously, once you know the start of a partition, that gives you the end of the previous one.

As you can see, you need to *know* what the file's character encoding is.  But if you do know that, you can quickly and reliably find a suitable place to set a partition boundary.

---

> The only problem comes is when there are text qualifiers in the data i.e. the configured record delimiters could also be a part of the data.

Well that could be difficult:

- If the delimiters are set just once at or near the start, then you simply read from the start until you figure out what the delimiters.  Then do the partitioning.
- If the delimiters could be changed anywhere in the file, then reading with a single thread may be the only option.  (Maybe you could parallelize the processing after you have broken the input into delimited records or lines or whatever.)
- One final option would be for the threads to partition and process *assuming* one delimiter, but also look for the embedded "change delimiters" instructions.  If they do detect an actual change, tell the threads for later partitions to start again.  It's a bit complicated ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The answer to the first point on multiple readers is that the processing done on the data is CPU bound and hence doing it concurrently would be effective. About the second point on determining the relevant boundary, yes your logic should work. The only problem comes is when there are text qualifiers in the data i.e. the configured record delimiters could also be a part of the data. So the second thread would not be able to determine the start pointer where it should start reading the next record.

Comment: To implement your solution I used CountingInputStream (guava - so I can determine the end pointer of the boundary) and InputStreamReader (so that I can read characters) but InputStreamReader internally used StreamDecoder which has a default buffer size of 8kb. Since it uses bufferring I cannot determine the exact record boundary after I skip the bytes based on split file size. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please have a look at the solution I added in my description and let me know if you have any inputs. About your suggestion on delimiters, I do not see it working (or may be I didn't completely understand it). Basically if we skip a calculated number of bytes we could end up in between a record where the text qualifier could already be started. Also note that few records could not even have the record delimiter as part of the data (i.e. no text qualifier) so predicting it becomes more difficult. The above solution works when there are no text qualifiers in the input.

Answer (score 1):

What you propose is not possible. All I/O operations on disks are inherently serial. Just think how a common harddrive looks like. The file is stored on ONE platter with ONE reading head. You won't create more heading heads from java - so even if you create multiple readers, they will end up waiting for each other to finish reading.

Also, ALL reading starts at the file start. You cannot start reading a file in the middle. If you want to seek the reading forward, you can use the skip() method, but that method *reads* that many characters without doing anything with the data.

EDIT: You can separate reading thread from processing threads. Create one reading thread to read the file from the beginning to the end. Each time it finishes reading an appropriate part of the file, it would start a new thread that would process the read data. Meanwhile, the reading thread will read a new file chunk, start a thread to that chunk, etc... When the reading thread reaches the end of the file, it terminates, having started several new threads that are now concurrently processing their respective parts of the file.

Comment: OP says processing is involved too

Comment: @idursun I am just saying that concurently reading the file will not offer any speedup.

Comment: @JakubZaverka - I understand the hardware restriction but since the thread reading the file data also processes it which takes time. Processing data involves validating, filtering, converting and transforming data which is a time consuming operation and can be parallelized. Also I understand that calling skip() will read the characters but that concurrent reads proves to be faster than single threaded read since data processing is a slow operation.

Comment: @JakubZaverka - I tried that and the processing is already done by a separate thread. To add more concurrency to application by reading multiple split files concurrently gives a huge gain and helps to improve the scalability of the application

Comment: @JakubZaverka - An additional advantage with having multiple readers is that the application can scale horizontally.

Comment: @Andy no matter how many readers you have, they would still be waiting for each other, provided they read the same single file.

Answer (score 0):

Please read about hadoop, and HDFS. They are designed to do same. There are many tutorials available for net. Please be more clear on what kind of processing you want to do.

Comment: Please have a look at the update in the description for the hadoop suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this: UTF-8 characters can have different lengths. So, just having the file length as hint, it is impossible to determine where x% of the characters end.

Comment: Right I understand and hence the question

Comment: Well but in that case you can only read through the file to find the limits. Which is what you explicitly said you didn't want.

Comment: So do you have any other ideas/suggestions on virtually splitting input file

Comment: Well, if you let the splits overlap (by how much i'm not sure, 1 to 3 byte i think), then you can be sure that at least for one split, the character is fully in the split. However, then you need to have some measure to figure out whether or not a character is processed twice. Also, the beginning character then maybe looks like a valid UTF-8 character but in fact is just a part of a character. So still not easy, but maybe this is a suggestion that gives you some new ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach to something like this is to have a single reader responsible for partitioning the data and as each partition boundary is reached by the reader, it submits the partition to a processing queue. You can then have a pool of processors that read from the queue. In this way, if processing a partition is slower than reading one, you gain the benefit of processing partitions in parallel.

Comment: With this approach the application can scale only vertically i.e. by adding more cores to a machine, while if we can have multiple readers to the same file the application can scale horizontally too i.e. by spawning a new jvm on a different machine which internally spawns multiple threads for reading, processing and writing.

Comment: I understand why you would want to scale horizontally, but I'm not sure that this problem lends itself to that. In my experience, adding more readers will result in more data needing to be read and a net reduction in throughput overall.